# What statistical test(s) should i use to test each of the following hypotheses?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics, panel-data, finance

The outcome variable is financial distress with 3 categories while the independent variables are financial factors and are continuous (about 12 of them).

- $H_0$: Financial factors have no impact on the financial distress states.
- $H_0$: financial factors when controlled for Macroeconomic factors have no significant impact on financial distress states.
- $H_0$: Determinant factors of each of the three financial distress states categories are not different.

Comment: The first two could be tested by likelihood ratio tests of multinomial logistic regression models, the first being a comparison of the model with all financial factors to an intercept-only model and the second a comparison of the model with financial factors and macroeconomic factors to a model with just macroeconomic factors. I don't follow exactly what you mean in the third hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

When your predictors (i.v.) are continuous and your outcome variable (financial distress) is categorical level, most likely your best statistical test is simply  **logistic regression**.

I hope this helps, good luck with your research!

Comment: Logistic regression is a model and does not perform any kind of hypothesis test on its own.

Comment: Ah apologies, in applications such as SPSS the type of hypothesis test is simply named after the model. More specific in this case (since your dependent var has 3 categories, it would be the 'multinomial logistic regression test'

Comment: Multinomial logistic regression isn't a test, either.